# How does fromInteger work?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, overloading, typeclass

I have this data structure:

```
data Fraction = Fraction Integer Integer
          | NaF
          deriving (Show)
```

Its supposed to represent Fractional numbers and I'm trying to make it Num instance. I didn't have problem with any operations apart from "fromInteger". I don't undersand what it is supposed to do and how it should look like. Can i please aks for help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is supposed to take an `Integer` and return a Fraction. In case of a fraction, it can just be `fromInteger n = Fraction n 1`